# Django can't access raw_post_data

Tags: python, django

I am experiencing a strange thing with Django, here is my views.py:

```
def api(request):
    return HttpResponse("%s %s" % (request.method,request.raw_post_data))
```

Now I make an HTTP POST with POSTMAN (small app for google chrome).

I set POSTMAN to make a POST request with 'test' in the raw field.

Django returns me 3 different thing (random):

Sometime Django returns 'GET' sometime nothing at all and sometime:

```
AttributeError at /
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'raw_post_data'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://api.mywebsiteurl.com/
Django Version: 1.6.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'raw_post_data'
Exception Location: /home/spice_dj/spice/views.py in api, line 17
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/South-0.8.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/home/spice_dj']
Server time:    Wed, 12 Mar 2014 22:51:11 -0400
```

1. Why Django returns me 'GET' when I clearly make a POST request?
2. Why does it return me that error?
3. Why it does not return me the 'test' that I set in the raw field?

Answer (score 43):

According to [django 1.6 deprecation timeline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-6):

> The attribute `HttpRequest.raw_post_data` was renamed to
>   `HttpRequest.body` in 1.4. The backward compatibility will be removed –
>   `HttpRequest.raw_post_data` will no longer work.

The motivation is described in the [relevant ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17323):

> `request.raw_post_dat`a is a bad name. It has nothing to do with `POST` in
>   particular, it's just the body of the HTTP request. This confuses
>   users, and makes it look like Django doesn't understand how HTTP
>   works. We should change the name to `request.body` and start a
>   deprecation process.

Use `request.body`:

```
def api(request):
    return HttpResponse("%s %s" % (request.method, request.body))
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: `RawPostDataException: you cannot access body after reading from request's data stream`
Getting this Error

Comment: @Chranjit make sure you are not accessing request.body multiple times, as you can  only read the request data stream once. Also, you can't access request.body after accessing request.POST.