# json parsing in django

Tags: python, json, django

I've built a webhook to receive json `POST`. However, I'm recieving an error from json decoder. Here's the view.py file from the webhook

```
import json
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import UserText

# Create your views here.
@csrf_exempt
@require_POST
def webhookmb(request):
    usrtxt = json.loads(request.body)

    UserText.objects.create(
        id = usrtxt['id'],
        recipient = usrtxt['recipient'],
        originator = usrtxt['originator'],
        body = usrtxt['body'],
        createdDatetime = usrtxt['createdDatetime'],
    )

    # redirect to API.AI
    # TODO


    return HttpResponse(200)
```

This is the error I am receiving

```
2017-07-09T00:19:45.559146+00:00 app[web.1]: Internal Server Error: /webhookmb/
2017-07-09T00:19:45.559154+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-07-09T00:19:45.559155+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
2017-07-09T00:19:45.559156+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_respon
se
2017-07-09T00:19:45.559157+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
2017-07-09T00:19:45.559155+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = get_response(request)
2017-07-09T00:19:45.559159+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
2017-07-09T00:19:45.559158+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_respon
se
2017-07-09T00:19:45.559160+00:00 app[web.1]:     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
2017-07-09T00:19:45.559159+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_v
iew
2017-07-09T00:19:45.559161+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py", line 40, in inner
2017-07-09T00:19:45.559161+00:00 app[web.1]:     return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
2017-07-09T00:19:45.559162+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/webhookmb/views.py", line 12, in webhookmb
2017-07-09T00:19:45.559162+00:00 app[web.1]:     usrtxt = json.loads(request.body)
2017-07-09T00:19:45.559163+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
2017-07-09T00:19:45.559163+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
2017-07-09T00:19:45.559164+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
2017-07-09T00:19:45.559165+00:00 app[web.1]:     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
2017-07-09T00:19:45.559165+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
2017-07-09T00:19:45.559166+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
2017-07-09T00:19:45.559170+00:00 app[web.1]: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I'm not quite sure how to approach fixing this, I've trouble shot a bunch of things however I'm stumped on how to fix `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` Any feedback would be amazing. Thanks!

Comment: could it be that the client is not sending a proper json to your server?

Comment: What version of django is this? Maybe you can try printing request.POST, request.body, etc. to see the data being sent? Similar question might be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368190/django-cant-access-raw-post-data.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to an encoding mismatch.

As you haven't provided the json itself.

Try this instead.

```
json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
```